# unable to get Lightagallery js to work: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'modules' of undefined

Tags: lightgallery

i've already seen some user with the same problem:

[Lightgallery not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459862/lightgallery-not-working)

but i still can't get it to work, here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css"></style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightGallery.css" /> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lg-thumbnail.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lg-fullscreen.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#lightgallery").lightGallery({
    selector: '.item'});
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="row">

 <ul class="lightgallery" id="lightgallery">
      <li a class="item" href="images/accessori1.jpg"><img src="images/accessori1.jpg"></a>
      </li>
      <li <a class="item" href="images/accessori1.jpg"><img src="images/accessori1.jpg"></a>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can't figure out what i'm missing.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is the problem?

Comment: I'm trying to make a grid of photos, and when i click on a photo the lightgallery should start.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't connect main file - lightgallery.js.
Connect it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this code and see if it does any help? Hope it does :)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css"></style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightGallery.css" /> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lg-thumbnail.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lg-fullscreen.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#lightgallery").lightGallery({
    selector: '.item'});
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="row">

 <ul class="lightgallery" id="lightgallery">
      <li a class="item" href="images/accessori1.jpg"><img src="images/accessori1.jpg"></a></li>
      <li ><a class="item" href="images/accessori1.jpg"><img src="images/accessori1.jpg"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```